# Why does calling remove() on an iterator give a ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I am trying to write a very simple method to remove duplicates in a LinkedList:

I try to do this without using additional buffer, so I maintain two iterators on the linked list, one does the normal iteration, and another iterates through all prior nodes to check for dupes (as indicated in CareerCup); however, the compiler tells me there is a CME even though I am calling itr1.remove():

```
public static void RemoveWithoutBuffer(LinkedList l) {
    ListIterator itr1 = l.listIterator();   
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    while (itr1.hasNext()) {
        Object next = itr1.next();
        count1++;
        count2 = 0;
        ListIterator itr2 = l.listIterator();
        while (itr2.hasNext()) {
            count2++;
            if (count2 == count1)
                break;
            if (itr2.next() == next){
                itr1.remove();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Another simpler solution of this problem with the aid of hashset is easy as follows, and no exception reported:

```
    public static void Remove(LinkedList l) {
    HashSet set = new HashSet();
    ListIterator itr = l.listIterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Object next = itr.next();
        if (set.contains(next))
            itr.remove();
        else
            set.add(next);
    }
}
```

Is it because when I am iterating through itr2 I cannot modify on itr1? Is there a way to fix this? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case yes - you're altering the collection's contents via iterator2, while iterator1 is not aware about the changes. In the second case HashSet/HashMap don't allow removing elements while iterating through them.

You can add removed elements to another collection, and removeAll them after an iteration. E.g.

```
    List toRemove = new ArrayList();
    for (Object next : collection) {
        if (someCondition) toRemove.add(next);
    }
    collection.removeAll(toRemove);
```

I hope it helps.

P.S. more details on how to remove elements from list, concerning algorithm complexity you can read here [Removing ArrayList object issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961639/removing-arraylist-object-issue/9961679#9961679)

Comment: Thank you. The solution is great but still consume some extra space, though I guess it saves more space compared to using hashSet. Thanks for the link too.

Comment: If space is concern, you can mark elements as deleted (i.e. set to null for lists, or use special keys with "isRemoved" property for sets and perform actual removal later).

Answer (score 3):

From [the API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator`
>   methods are *fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   Iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a
>   `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting CME because the list is modified by second iterator and first iterator is not aware of that change. When next time it tries to access the list, it is already modified. And hence it throws the exception.

Please use only one iterator to modify list at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can think of it this way: when you create an iterator it gets the list's current "modification count".  When an iterator removes an element from the list, it checks the modification count to see if it is what it expects, and if all is okay, it removes the element and updates the modification count on both the iterator and the list.  The other iterator will still have the old modification count and see the new value and throw the CME.

The hashset based way is the right solution in most cases.  It will perform much better--two O(n) passes is usually better than O(n^2) as the nested iteration solution would produce (if it worked).

Comment: Thank you! So I guess there is no way really to use 2 iterators to remove the item in place without resorting to extra space? The solution Eugene gave is great but still consume some extra space. Yes, timewise, it's bad, just want to try out in case there are requirements on not using temp buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get CME was explained by others, here is possible way you can use to remove dups

Use a List `toRemove` to record element at the first time `iterator` stumble into it, afterwards when meet again with the recorded element, remove it using `iterator.remove()`

 `private void removeDups(List list) {
        List toRemove = new ArrayList();
        for(Iterator  it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Object next = it.next();
            if(!toRemove.contains(next)) {
                toRemove.add(next);
            } else {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
        toremove.clear();
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can fix this without using extra space.

The problem comes from executing these two lines, one after another.

- itr1.remove();
- itr2.hasNext();

You can use two iterators over the same list at the same time. **If you are careful**.
But once one of those iterators has modified the list (as it happens with `itr1.remove()` ) you can no longer use the other iterator (so you can't call `itr2.hasNext()`).

The solution is to put a `break` after `itr1.remove()`. And to update `count1` :

```
public static void RemoveWithoutBuffer(LinkedList l) {
    ListIterator itr1 = l.listIterator();   
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    while (itr1.hasNext()) {
        Object next = itr1.next();
        count1++;
        count2 = 0;
        ListIterator itr2 = l.listIterator();
        while (itr2.hasNext()) {
            count2++;
            if (count2 == count1)
                break;
            if (itr2.next() == next){
                itr1.remove();
                --count1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A more elegant solution would be to compare with elements after the current one rather than elements before the current one :

```
public static void RemoveWithoutBuffer(LinkedList l) {
  ListIterator itr1 = l.listIterator();
  while (itr1.hasNext()) {
    Object next = itr1.next();
    ListIterator itr2 = l.listIterator( itr1.nextIndex() );
    while (itr2.hasNext()) {
      if (itr2.next() == next) {
        itr1.remove();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These are not the best solutions in terms of computational complexity. If memory space is not an issue the hashset solution is a better one regarding computational complexity.

But the question is about concurrent mofication through iterators and not about complexity optimization.